# Issue checking a .txt file for an element using a while() loop

Tags: java, arrays, file, while-loop

I'm writing a program that asks a user to log in and checks if their ID is inside a file "Employees.txt" and if it is then it will print out VALID __ ID if they're a Manager or an Assistant. But when I enter an invalid ID, say "x" in and then try again, it loops forever, not checking if the ID is valid. How can I fix this issue? I have Employees.txt in the same directory as Account.java and

```
E12,Manager
E13,Assistant
```

is what's inside the file. Any help would be appreciated as I've tried everything I could. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Account
{
    public static String  accountInput;
    public static boolean inSystem      = true;
    public static boolean displayLogIn  = true;
    public static boolean managerLogIn  = false;
    public static Scanner userInput     = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static File stockFile        = new File("Stock.txt");
    public static File employeesFile    = new File("Employees.txt");
    public static File transactionsFile = new File("Transactions.txt");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String[] contents;
        System.out.println("\tWorking Files");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Stock File:\t\tStock.txt\nEmployee File:\t\tEmployees.txt\nTransactions File:\tTransactions.txt\n\n");
        Scanner readEmployeesFile = new Scanner(employeesFile);
        while(inSystem)
        {
            while(displayLogIn)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Employee ID(i.e E1)\tEnter Q to Quit Program.\nEnter here: ");
                accountInput = userInput.nextLine();

                while(readEmployeesFile.hasNextLine())
                {
                    contents = readEmployeesFile.nextLine().split(",");
                    if(contents[0].equals(accountInput) & contents[1].equals("Manager"))
                    {
                        displayLogIn = false;
                        System.out.print("Valid MGR ID");
                        inSystem     = false;
                    }
                    else if(contents[0].equals(accountInput) & contents[1].equals("Assistant"))
                    {
                        displayLogIn = false;
                        System.out.print("Valid AST ID");
                        inSystem     = false;
                    }
                    else if(accountInput.equals("Q"))
                    {
                        displayLogIn = false;
                        inSystem     = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you open the `Scanner` inside the loop, forcing it to read all the contents of the file on the first iteration. This means that the condition in `while(readEmployeesFile.hasNextLine())` will always evaluate to `false` after the first iteration and the loop will never be entered again. For this reason only the first trial may be valid, afterwards your loop cannot terminate.

Here is adjusted code that worked for me:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Account
{
    public static String  accountInput;
    public static boolean inSystem      = true;
    public static boolean displayLogIn  = true;
    public static Scanner userInput     = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static File employeesFile    = new File("Employees.txt");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        List<String[]> contents = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("\tWorking Files");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Stock File:\t\tStock.txt\nEmployee File:\t\tEmployees.txt\nTransactions File:\tTransactions.txt\n\n");
        Scanner readEmployeesFile = new Scanner(employeesFile);
        while(readEmployeesFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] current = readEmployeesFile.nextLine().split(",");
            contents.add(current);
        }
        while(inSystem)
        {
            while(displayLogIn)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Employee ID(i.e E1)\tEnter Q to Quit Program.\nEnter here: ");
                accountInput = userInput.nextLine();

                for(String[] content: contents) {
                    if (content[0].equals(accountInput) & content[1].equals("Manager")) {
                        displayLogIn = false;
                        System.out.print("Valid MGR ID");
                        inSystem = false;
                    } else if (content[0].equals(accountInput) & content[1].equals("Assistant")) {
                        displayLogIn = false;
                        System.out.print("Valid AST ID");
                        inSystem = false;
                    } else if (accountInput.equals("Q")) {
                        displayLogIn = false;
                        inSystem = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        readEmployeesFile.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the input file is read a single time **before** entering the loop and stores all the lines in `contents` which is now of type `List<String[]>`. In the `for` loop you simply need to check the contents of the file that have already been read.

On a side note, you should always close the resources that you are using. In this case I refer to the `Scanner` object and this is why I included the line `readEmployeesFile.close();` after your loop.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of removing the while from inside the other 2 while loops and do it outside, I never knew how to do it but having looked at your solution, I do now! Thanks alot!

Comment: You are welcome. You should keep in mind that reading files from the disk is an expensive operation, so the number of such operations should be minimized. This means that you should read the file only once and use its content afterwards. It is a bad idea to open the same file multiple times, unless it cannot fit into memory or you have another good reason to do that.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter an ID, you start looping on your file to see if that ID matches.

You reach the end of the file. `readEmployeesFile.hasNextLine()` is false. So you iterate again, read the next ID.

But the `readEmployeesFile` is still at the end of the file. There is nothing that takes it back to the beginning. So when it gets to the `while` again, `readEmployeesFile.hasNextLine()` is *still* false.

Possible solutions:

- Open the scanner, `readEmployeesFile`, not at the beginning of the method, but right before you use it. Then close it right after you reach the end of the file. So you will be opening and closing it every time the user enters an ID.
- Read all the IDs from the file into a `Map` before you start prompting the user, and then look for the ID in that map instead of directly in the file. This would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
contents[0].equals(accountInput) & contents[1].equals("Manager")
contents[0].equals(accountInput) & contents[1].equals("Assistant")
```

to

```
contents[0].equals(accountInput) && contents[1].equals("Manager")
contents[0].equals(accountInput) && contents[1].equals("Assistant")
```

The **AND** operator is represented with a double ampersand (&&), not one.

Comment: In Java, both are valid. You can use `&` or `&&` - the difference is just short-circuiting. So this is not the reason for the problem the OP has.

Comment: This is not really the problem of this program.

Comment: '&' evaluates both sides of the operation, unlike '&&' that evaluates them one by one. (if the first is true, pass to the next one)

Comment: Thanks for that but as the other 2 stated, it's not the main issue of my code, when I still enter an invalid ID and then enter a valid ID it doesn't state that it is a valid ID.